# custom login controller action grails no render after authentication

Tags: grails, spring-security

My grails 2.2 app has a simple custom form based login controller that authenticates the user against an external system and returns a boolean response. If successful response it calls the reauthenticate method, updates the session, and redirects.

```
springSecurityService.reauthenticate(thisuser.username)
session['SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT'] = SecurityContextHolder.context
if (springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
println "Redirecting to postauth"
redirect(action: 'postauth')
 }
```

**The problem is after redirect a new page will not render**. From the user's perspective the login page doesn't change after clicking the login button even though in the logs the user is logged and has an active session with authentication. If you click the button to go to the homepage though, it shows the user as authenticated and all is well, but not until this or some other action is taken. Read everything I could find in the documentation and similar stackoverflow questions but I'm stuck here.

**Logs**

```
pid.authenticateads: [juser:testuser, action:authenticateads, controller:pid]
ADS Validation:true
testuser is logged in
Authentication org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@1927f6c4: Principal: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUser@ba7ee5b2: Username: testuser; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN
Session Content:
  SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT = org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@1927f6c4: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@1927f6c4: Principal: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUser@ba7ee5b2: Username: testuser; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN
Redirecting to postauth
pid.postauth: [action:postauth, controller:pid]
In postauth action, redirecting to Cluster controller, action search
cluster.search: [action:search, controller:cluster]
```

Tried to add some additional unnecessary redirects just to ensure the principal was getting passed, but the problem is at render. The search gsp is basically blank to eliminate any resource plugin layout problems for testing. Debugging is turned on and there are no render errors or resources errors. It makes the call to display the page but nothing actually updates. Again if I go to the browser and manually change the url after logging in it shows the user logged in. Also tried clearing the cachedRequestMaps and all the sessionfixationprevention options.

```
class ClusterController {

    def springSecurityService

    def search() {
        def user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
        println "In Cluster controller, action: search, user: "+user.username
    }
```

Comment: In your clusterController after method execution search it will looking for search.gsp, if not found it will display blank. But if you want to redirect then you need to write redirect statement in search method.

Comment: I've tried lots of different redirects, thats not the issue, the issue is none of them will render a page. This all worked fine when using the default j_spring_security_check so I'm missing something that happens in that workflow but I can't determine what exactly. Some filter perhaps.

Comment: Have you tried to put annotation on search() for authentication?

Comment: just show your code of redirected action... So I can get idea what's the missing thing. I am little bit confuse about your question and comment.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by throwing out what I was doing and writing a custom authentication provider and filter. http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1090